# p:datatable slow render

Tags: performance, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have got a datatable with 31 columns and 60 rows that renders pretty slow. It renders cells one by one. The performance is not database related, I've created mocked dataset that showed same performance. I'm not able to reduce the columns, need to show a full month at once.

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 and there is no option to upgrade.

Is there any trick to speed up rendering?

I've created got the following datatable:

```
    <p:dataTable id="calendar" value="#{calendarView.calendarData.entrySet().toArray()}" var="row" frozenColumns="1" scrollable="true" >
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column headerText="#{msgs.calendar_roomNumber}" style="text-align: right; float:right; width:100px;"/>
                <c:forEach items="#{calendarView.columnData}" var="column">
                    <p:column headerText="#{column}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
        <p:column headerText="Szoba">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.key.roomNumber}" />
        </p:column>
        <c:forEach items="#{calendarView.columnData}" var="column">
            <p:column style="background-color:#{not empty row.value[column]?row.value[column].getRoomState().toString():''}">
                <h:outputText value="SZ" id="column#{column}" rendered="#{empty row.value[column]}" />
                <p:tooltip id="toolTipFadeColumn#{column}" for="column#{column}" position="top" escape="false" value="#{row.value[column].label}" />


                <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty row.value[column] and row.value[column].endStaying}" value="-&gt;" id="columnend#{column}"/>
                <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty row.value[column] and row.value[column].startStaying}" value="&lt;-" id="columnstart#{column}"/>

                <p:tooltip id="toolTipFadeEnd#{column}" for="columnend#{column}" position="top" escape="false" value="#{row.value[column].label}" rendered="#{not empty row.value[column].label}"/>
                <p:tooltip id="toolTipFadeStart#{column}" for="columnstart#{column}" position="top" escape="false" value="#{row.value[column].label}" rendered="#{not empty row.value[column].label}"/>
            </p:column>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:dataTable>
```

calendarData has 60 element and has `Map<Room,Map<Long,RoomCell>>` structure with the following beans:

```
public class RoomCell {
    private boolean endStaying=false;
    private boolean startStaying=false;
    private RoomState roomState=RoomState.FREE;
    private String labels;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room extends AbstractModelImpl implements Comparable{

    @Column(name = "room_number", unique = true)
    private int roomNumber;

    @Column(name="room_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoomType roomType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Staying> stayings;
...
}
```

Comment: just to understand something `c:foreach` is like a loop ?!?

Comment: Why doing something like that in the `xhtml`, you can generate your loop and make the first construction of it in the `Managedbean`.

Comment: @Hubidubi: Provide this problem from a developer side. Where is the delay? Client-side? Server side (check with browser developer tools) If client-side: is it a problem with all browsers? Or e.g. just with IE-9?  And please always create an [mcve], especially if you mocked things, then you kind of already have almost)

Comment: @Kukeltje c:foreach is needed because I need to build datatable dynamically (number of columns can be between 28 and 31 as we are speaking of a month). Slowness is on client side, it takes about 20s to render the whole datatable. Drawing cells is slow. I've tested in chrome.

Comment: I did not say the foreach is not needed, that is @YagamiLight:  Did you try removing the tooltips? And what PF version are you using?. Did you profile the js on the client to see where the slowness is? And 'PrimeFaces' in the title is not needed since it is already tagged with that

Comment: I use v3.5, old project no chance to upgrade.

Comment: 1. Remove `p:tooltips`and see if it improves speed (use `title` attribute on `h:outputText` and see if thats ok for you) 2. You should shorten you component IDs for example `id="column#{column}"` to `id="t1#{column}"` (like text 1) 3. I have "same" table and for same data set it takes also 20 seconds to render table ...

Comment: @jNick: Also with PF3.5? Also in FF and Chrome?

Comment: Or in combination with using a title,  try moving the tooltip outside the loop and try if a PF Selector helps (or even try a 'global' tooltip, see the docs)

Comment: @Kukeltje locally for me it takes total of 15-20 seconds (for 7 seconds browser is waiting for server response / server generating html, and 5-7 seconds to receive that generated html because its 5MB page update and another 1-3 seconds depending on local machine load to render that html), while our strong production server it takes 1 sec to generate html, again 5 secs to transfer html and 1-3 sec to render. So these are my approximate statistics on max 10 page refresh. I did a lot optimizations here, like small component ID, use div instead p:spacer width: x, and others ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling  with dataTable I created optimized version of dataTable that has adequate (not perfect) performance. I made the following modifications:

- All inner loops (c:forEach) are removed
- All tooltips are replaced with title attribute

  ```
  <p:dataTable id="calendar" value="#{calendarView.calendarData.entrySet().toArray()}" var="row" frozenColumns="1" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="600"  scrollWidth="1300">
      <p:column style="width: 50px; text-align: right">
          <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="#{msgs.calendar_room}" />
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{row.key.roomNumber}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:columns value="#{calendarView.columns}" var="column" style="text-align: center; #{not empty row.value[column].color ? 'background-color:'.concat(row.value[column].color):''}">
          <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="#{column}" />
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText rendered="#{row.value[column].endStaying == true}" value="-&gt;" id="endStaying">
              <f:attribute name="title" value="#{row.value[column].label}" escape="true" />
          </h:outputText>
          <h:outputText rendered="#{row.value[column].startStaying == true}" value="&lt;-" id="startStaying" >
              <f:attribute name="title" value="#{row.value[column].label}" escape="true" />
          </h:outputText>
          <h:outputText rendered="#{row.value[column].endStaying == false and row.value[column].startStaying == false and not empty row.value[column].label}" value="-" id="staying" >
              <f:attribute name="title" value="#{row.value[column].label}" escape="true" />
          </h:outputText>
      </p:columns>
  </p:dataTable>
  ```